# how to use InstEd to edit MSI files?

Tags: windows-installer

Currently i have a Microsoft Software Installer and  wanted to edit that  MSI file which has a restriction saying it cannot be installed on a domain controller, I wanted to remove that restriction,
how can I do it using

> InstEd

software?

Comment: First things first: **when an MSI is marked as unsafe for installation on a domain controller I would never force its installation!** There must be a very good reason the MSI is trying to prevent this. What kind of software is this? You are dealing with a domain controller - probably the most dangerous type of server to test stuff on. Perhaps it is a virtual machine?

Comment: For what it is worth: I never down-vote questions - answers can be dangerous, questions generally are not. Do ask what you want, but please don't force an MSI like that to install on a domain controller. Hope you completed your task OK.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be answered without knowing how the restriction is implemented. If it is a launch condition, then it will show up in the LaunchConditions table; if it is custom action code then you'll need to look at the install UI and execute sequences to see if there are any custom actions that look like they might be the culprits. Either way, you'd delete or modify the appropriate place, but step by step guidance also depends on how much you know about the internals of MSI files.